# How to define attributes with the same key for different modules?

Tags: document, antora

I want to use the same key attribute in different module, but the value is different.

I defined attribute in antora.yml , but it seems no way to distinguish modules.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Attribute definitions in `antora.yml` are global to the component containing `antora.yml`. There is no way to target those attributes to a specific module. But they are easily overridden within the page that uses them.

For example, if you define an attribute in `antora.yml`:

```yaml
asciidoc:
  attributes:
    foo: bar
```

Then wherever you use `{foo}` in your component's pages, you'd see `bar` in the generated HTML.

To override that in a specific page:

```
:foo: FOO
```

When the `{foo}` attribute is encountered anywhere on the same page, after that definition, you'd see `FOO` in the generated HTML.

If you have multiple pages in a module that need to share the same definition, you can place those definitions into a separate Asciidoc file, say `attributes.adoc`. If you place that file into the module's `partials` folder, you can include it on any module page that requires the attribute definitions with:

```
include::partial$attributes.adoc[]
```

You don't have to define all attributes within `attributes.adoc`, only the ones that need to be redefined for the module.